# Hex of encrypted data: Trying to decrpt

Tags: java, encryption

I have data encrypted with AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

I have the secret key but no iv.

I am unable to decrypt the data. What exactly are the steps. I copied a page's steps but I am sure I am doing something wrong since the data is hex.

Below is my code. I use the decrypt function with two params.

```
public class DCrypt2 {
    private static String key = "3jiUqR/0J4/HX98XimcDvg==";//
    private static String msg ="636F98E19CCAEB9C6ED1095F70C4739AEBA6200E83926EA3DA42DA4A391AC08B";//"2925D99C3A7520D84D64A80AAFB20BF63B22B6A8017B7438598BE36419B71174";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] myIV = getIV(msg);
        byte[] myMSG = getMSG(msg);
        String my_msg = myMSG.toString();
        decrypt(msg, myIV);
        System.out.println("Second Try ");
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(msg);
        System.out.println("____________________________________");
        //System.out.println(Base64.getDecoder().decode(msg));
        //System.out.println(myDeHex(msg));
        //msg = myDeHex(msg);

        int extra = msg.length()%16;

        System.out.println(extra+" ok "+msg.length());
        for(int i = 0; i<extra;i++) {
            System.out.println("ANOTHER");
            msg +=" ";
        }
        System.out.println(extra+" ok "+msg.length());

    }

    public static String decrypt(String msg, byte[] iv) {
        try {

                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                    //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/nopadding");

                    SecretKeySpec the_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");// get / create symmetric encryption key
                    //SecretKeySpec the_key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(key), "AES");

                    // byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(msg);
                     IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, the_key, ivspec);


                    byte[] input = Base64.getEncoder().encode(msg.getBytes());
                    if(input.length%16 > 0 ) {
                        System.out.println(input.length%16);
                        input = Arrays.copyOf(input, (input.length)+(16-(input.length%16)));
                        System.out.println(input.length+ " my size");
                    }
                    String res = new String(cipher.doFinal( input));
                    //String res = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes("UTF-8")));
                    //String res = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
                    System.out.println("Results: "+res);
                    return res;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "";
            }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and then add a lot more info to your question: What page did you copy? What should the data be?

Comment: Without more information we can only guess, but it is common that the first 16 bytes of cipher are actually the IV, and the true cipher begins after that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good technical write-up here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3602#section-2

You need an Initialization Vector:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29134/precisely-how-does-cbc-mode-use-the-initialization-vector

> The IV's purpose is to ensure same plaintexts encrypt to different
> ciphertexts. When an adversary learns the IV after the plaintext has
> been encrypted, no harm is done, since it has already served its
> purpose.
>
> The IV can be made public after encryption, without impacting the
> security of the system. **Usually, it is prefixed to the ciphertext.**

[Source / More info](https://defuse.ca/cbcmodeiv.htm)